# How to fix 'missing FROM-clause entry for table'?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, plpgsql

I have a function with query. If condition is true, I update a row with new values.

I do a query:

```
SELECT * FROM transfer_flight(41313, '2017-08-15 20:00:00+05');
```

and I get an error:

> ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "flights"
>   LINE 1: SELECT (flights.scheduled_departure < $2)
>                  ^
>   QUERY:  SELECT (flights.scheduled_departure < $2)
>   CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function transfer_flight(integer,timestamp with time >zone) line 7 at IF

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION flightFunc(
    flight_identificator INTEGER, 
    new_timestamp timestamp with time zone) 
RETURNS TABLE(
    flight_id INTEGER,
    flight_no CHARACTER(6),
    departure_airport character(3),
    scheduled_departure timestamp with time zone,
    arrival_airport character(3),
    scheduled_arrival timestamp with time zone
)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
DECLARE 
    flight_d timestamp with time zone =  scheduled_arrival - 
scheduled_departure;

BEGIN

    IF (flights.scheduled_departure < $2)
    THEN
        UPDATE flights
            scheduled_departure = $2,
            scheduled_arrival = $2 + flight_d
        FROM flights
        WHERE flights.flight_id = $1
        RETURNING 
            flights.flight_id,  
            flights.flight_no,
            flights.departure_airport,
            flights.scheduled_departure,
            flights.arrival_airport,        
            flights.scheduled_arrival;
    END IF;

END;
$$;
```

In result I should need to update only one row with input flight_identificator

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `FROM` clause!  That does a `CROSS JOIN`.  And you need `SET`. So:

```
UPDATE flights
    SET scheduled_departure = $2,
        scheduled_arrival = $2 + flight_d
    WHERE flights.flight_id = $1
RETURNING 
    flights.flight_id,  
    flights.flight_no,
    flights.departure_airport,
    flights.scheduled_departure,
    flights.arrival_airport,        
    flights.scheduled_arrival;
```

Comment: I create a function. But when I calling function in query: SELECT * FROM transfer_flight(41313, '2017-08-15 20:00:00+05'); I get error from topic of this question

Answer (score 0):

I looks to me like  you should get rid of the `flight_d` variable and of the `IF` block, and move the logic to the query itself, like :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION flightFunc(
    flight_identificator INTEGER, 
    new_timestamp timestamp with time zone) 
RETURNS TABLE(
    flight_id INTEGER,
    flight_no CHARACTER(6),
    departure_airport character(3),
    scheduled_departure timestamp with time zone,
    arrival_airport character(3),
    scheduled_arrival timestamp with time zone
)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$

BEGIN

    UPDATE flights SET
        scheduled_departure = $2,
        scheduled_arrival = $2 + flights.scheduled_arrival - flights.scheduled_departure
    WHERE flights.flight_id = $1 AND flights.scheduled_departure < $2
    RETURNING 
        flights.flight_id,  
        flights.flight_no,
        flights.departure_airport,
        flights.scheduled_departure,
        flights.arrival_airport,        
        flights.scheduled_arrival;

END;
$$;
```